# Parse error when trying to run haskell function?

Tags: string, haskell, fold

I'm trying to write a Haskell function that uses folds and will take a string and return its "word value" as an int. This is the function:

```
import Data.Char

wordValue :: String -> Int
wordValue (x:xs) = foldr (\(ord(toLower x) - (ord 'a') + 1)) 0 xs
```

Basically, i'm trying to convert each character into a int value and use the 'foldr' function to accumulate the value. But, I'm getting the following error, which I don't understand:

```
Parse error in pattern: ord (toLower x) - (ord 'a') + 1
```

Comment: `\(ord(toLower x) - (ord 'a') + 1)` makes no sense.

Comment: `foldr` should also take two parameters: the item of the list, and the result of the `foldr` of the tail.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `foldr` function also take two parameters: the item of the list, and the result of the `foldr` of the tail. You thus should implement this as:

```
wordValue :: String -> Int
wordValue xs = foldr (\x ys -> ord (toLower x) - ord 'a' + ys + 1) 0 xs
```

where `x` is the character of the list, and `ys` is the result of folding the rest of the list (so the `wordValue` of the remaining elements).

But here it is simpler to just work with a mapping and summing these up, so:

```
wordValue :: String -> Int
wordValue = sum . map (\x -> ord (toLower x) - ord 'a' + 1)
```

Comment: @kashmafia Willem is quite good with his answers but judging by your question I suggest you focus narrowly (at first) on the lambda.  Willem's `(\x ys -> ...)` is proper Haskell.  Your `(\(ord(toLower x) - (ord 'a') + 1))` clearly indicated you had some notion but is totally bogus. Reflect on that.